# pandasで別のデータフレームへのappendがうまくできません

Tags: python, pandas

特定の行の最大値を調べ、その最大値が存在する行を別のデータフレームにappendさせたいのですが、
上手くappendできません。どうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 3, 2, 3], 'col2': [5, 0, 2, 1]})
print(df)
print(df["col2"].idxmax())

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 3, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 0, 2, 1]})
print(df)
df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()]

df1.append(df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()])
df1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの仕様や記事を参考に、戻り値を何かに代入する必要があります。
[pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

> Returns: DataFrame
> A new DataFrame consisting of the rows of caller and the rows of other.

[pandasのappendができない? もとのDataFrameは変更されないので、返り値を使う](https://linus-mk.hatenablog.com/entry/pandas_append_not_working)

> pandasでDataFrameにappendするとき、連結後のDataFrameは返り値になっている。もとのDataFrameは変更されない。

これではなく：

```
df1.append(df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()])
```

こうする必要があるわけですね。

```
df1 = df1.append(df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()])
```

Answer (score 0):

本題からは外れますが、Pandas version 1.4.0 では以下の様に warning message が表示されます。

```py
>>> pd.__version__
'1.4.0'
>>> df1.append(df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()])
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be
removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

以下は `append()` を使わない方法です。

```py
>>> df1.loc[len(df1)] = df.loc[df["col2"].idxmax()]
>>> df1
   col1  col2
0     0     5
1     3     0
2     2     2
3     3     1
4     0     4
```

Comment: なぜ、appendは廃止予定なのでしょうか？速度的、セキュリティ的などの問題を抱えているのでしょうか？

Comment: この議論 [Deprecate Series / DataFrame.append · Issue #35407 · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35407) を読んでみて下さい。